# How to save data from smartphone accelerometer?

Tags: react-native, expo, accelerometer, sensors

native and I have some vary basic questions. I want to have access in my accelerometer and gyroscope data from my smartphone. I found some code in expo tutorial which works fine with my device and i have a decent understanding of it. The problem is that this app shows the wanted values on my smartphone screen while i also want them to be saved. Any ideas how to do that? Here is the code:

````
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { Accelerometer } from 'expo-sensors';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0,
  });
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(null);

  const _slow = () => {
    Accelerometer.setUpdateInterval(1000);
  };

  const _fast = () => {
    Accelerometer.setUpdateInterval(16);
  };

  const _subscribe = () => {
    setSubscription(
      Accelerometer.addListener(accelerometerData => {
        setData(accelerometerData);
      })
    );
  };

  const _unsubscribe = () => {
    subscription && subscription.remove();
    setSubscription(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    _subscribe();
    return () => _unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const { x, y, z } = data;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Accelerometer: (in Gs where 1 G = 9.81 m s^-2)</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        x: {round(x)} y: {round(y)} z: {round(z)}
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={subscription ? _unsubscribe : _subscribe} style={styles.button}>
          <Text>{subscription ? 'On' : 'Off'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={_slow} style={[styles.button, styles.middleButton]}>
          <Text>Slow</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={_fast} style={styles.button}>
          <Text>Fast</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

function round(n) {
  if (!n) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Math.floor(n * 100) / 100;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    padding: 10,
  },
  middleButton: {
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
  },
});```
Ideally I need it to be saved in csv or json format. Thank you
````

Comment: You can safe data in the phone storage with [react-native-async-storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/)

Comment: I try to figure out how this works but i find the documentation very poor. Maybe it is because my lack of experience. For example where is this data stored?

Comment: May be a bit late. This is stored locally on your phone and only gets deleted when you delete the app on ios or delete the app/appstorage on android